# Should I resize my object localization dataset in order to train a fully convolutional network?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, dataset, cnn, data-augmentation

I want to create a fully-convolutional neural net that trains on wider face datasets in order to draw bounding box around faces. The dataset is highly diverse in the image sizes. So my question is, are there no better ways other than to resize the image in order to train a fully convolutional network? Even if there is no other way than to resize the input image what should I do about the annotated bounding boxes? I do not wish to manually annotate all bounding boxes after resizing the images.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to predict box coordinates around faces? Exactly which sort of architecture do you have in mind?

Comment: A simple one. Nothing complex. It is going to be a sliding window implemented convolutionally network. It will have a bunch of conv layers, batch norm, max pool, linear layer implemented convolutionally with swish activation.

Comment: This is essentialy the first time I am doing a object localization problem. However I am planning to increase it's effectiveness by introducing other things such as deformable conv layers, roi pooling  etc.